# MVC 5 ValidateAntiForgeryToken Ajax Post not working when logged in

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, antiforgerytoken

**Background**

I have read a lot of the other posts on this site with similar issues but nothing specifically related to mine. I am also a student at Uni and trying to apply my education to real world issues to get a deeper understanding of MVC but every step of the way has been a monumental effort. (we studied Laravel which was even more challenging). This is my first post and I am looking forward to your help.

**Issue**

'Logging in' stops ajax posts working.

I have a form with drop downs that are populated from a database. The purpose of the drop downs is to configure a product ordering string. Once a drop down is changed, it triggers an ajax post that sends the form details back to a controller method that searches the database for ordering strings that could be a match and repopulate the form with only the options possible based on the selected configuration.

This works fine when anonymous but when logged in it won't make it past the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute on the controller.

Everything is fine when I comment out the attribute.

After a bit of research, it seems the issue is related to the fact that the token is set against usernames and  when logging in the username changes and the token hash is incorrect.

I have tried AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true; in Application_Start() to no avail.

If this is the case, I have 2 questions:

1. How do I refresh the token upon logging in?
2. If I am only posting drop down content through ajax, do I really need to use anti forgery tokens?  (I would assume every post requires them).
3. Do I need a different attribute ie: **[Authorize]** or **[AllowAnonymous]**?

If not the case, then what else could I look at?

**View** (_config.cshtml)

```
@model HomeWeb.Models.RtcgConfigurationModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("updateDB", "Rtcg", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =    "multipart/form-data" }))

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h3>Configure RTCG</h3>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgCabinetType, "Cabinet Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgCabinetType, Model.Cabinets, new { onchange = "changed();" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgCabinetType)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgAdaptorType, "Adaptor Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgAdaptorType, Model.Adaptors, new { onchange = "changed();" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgAdaptorType)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgQtyAdaptors, "Adaptor Qty.", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgQtyAdaptors, Model.AdaptorQtys, new { onchange = "changed();" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgQtyAdaptors)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgTerminationMethod, "Termination", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgTerminationMethod, Model.TerminationMethods)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgTerminationMethod)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgFaceplateStyle, "Faceplate Style", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgFaceplateStyle, Model.FacePlateStyles)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgFaceplateStyle)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgScreenPrinting, "Screenprinting", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgScreenPrinting, Model.ScreenPrintOptions)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgScreenPrinting)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgApplication, "Fibre Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgApplication, Model.Applications)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgApplication)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgVerminProof, "Vermin Proof", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgVerminProof, Model.VerminProofing)

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgVerminProof)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Get Quotation" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: none"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changed() {
        var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
        var headers = {};
        headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = token;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Rtcg/Ajax_DropdownChanged',
            type: "POST",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            headers: headers,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#config-form').html(result);
            },
        })

    }
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
// POST: handle dropdown changes from Ajax
      [HttpPost]       
      [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Ajax_DropdownChanged(RtcgConfigurationModel formData)
        {  
            //handle 'postback' displaying the fields. 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
                RtcgConfigurationModel model = new RtcgConfigurationModel();
                using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    model.Cabinets = DisplayElement.Cabinets(formData);
                    model.Adaptors = DisplayElement.Adaptors(formData);
                    model.AdaptorQtys = DisplayElement.AdaptorQuantities(formData);
                    model.TerminationMethods = DisplayElement.Termination(formData);
                    model.FacePlateStyles = DisplayElement.Faceplates(formData);
                    model.ScreenPrintOptions = DisplayElement.ScreenPrinting(formData);
                    model.Applications = DisplayElement.Application(formData);
                    model.VerminProofing = DisplayElement.VerminProof(formData);   
                }
                return PartialView("_config", model);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

When not logged in I get a single token string.

> "__RequestVerificationToken=Rt3m8M0YJeJ9u1TENd19Mx6wDxtU6FE208nRAOjo7Py6tkyH_pZdJfgPiXDt70UqJCf_fwasRA_7Ekc792khXWMXDzWS8x3wfXDoWNIZQVQ1&RtcgCabinetType=RTC2G&RtcgAdaptorType=LCD&RtcgQtyAdaptors=06&RtcgTerminationMethod=FS&RtcgFaceplateStyle=Z&RtcgScreenPrinting=SP&RtcgApplication=SM&RtcgVerminProof=N"

However, when logged in I get 2 tokens (even when following Stephens suggestion below and removing the header).

> "__RequestVerificationToken=d21oW7noP0WBLI_3ubvpPo7uHYPbIrsq0VzeIXgNNaxmPiMiA8IBr2N2qU3wepup5X46gpy4VaFDc_MfUhCE-SADGhwplraMk4PFt-72GpnsxTeGW2COOggVhFEAXvRyb_ofh3d-ax3Zc1twpfenUw2&__RequestVerificationToken=v0g2f1ukJlO9g1WyXqh6GS3PB_YXHo9rY75BD1Wf8voQFMMbwDFE4nKJRV20orE5nm0EBIj4LOWlo_JdUfFvm2A-364nbEwEdEyHDcJ0tVjmqYTbH1AAorg0b347vSB3KLZ00sulasO9A9_28erP0A2&RtcgCabinetType=RTC2G&RtcgAdaptorType=LCD&RtcgQtyAdaptors=06&RtcgTerminationMethod=FS&RtcgFaceplateStyle=Z&RtcgScreenPrinting=SP&RtcgApplication=SM&RtcgVerminProof=N"

Comment: You don't need to add `headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = token;`- your `data: $('form').serialize(),` code is already serializing the token and sending it in the request.

Comment: Hi Stephen. Thanks for the super quick response. When posting the form data through ajax, it doesn't seem to be seen by the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute unless I post the token in the header. I tried to comment them out but it didn't work at all, logged in or otherwise.

Comment: There is no need to do that at all.

Comment: Yeah, I have been reading conflicting information about it. Unfortunately, I don't really have the depth of understanding about how the posted data is handled by the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute. If you are able to explain how it handles it in laymans terms it would be great. Of course, if I could get this to work it would be even better. Is there any other area that could be causing the issue?

Comment: What you have shown (excluding duplicating the token in the header) should work fine, so not sure what the issue is. What is the error message displayed in the response (browsers Network tab) when you make the ajax call?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I am getting internal server error 500.

Comment: Yes I know, but what are the details of the error? (use your browser tools - the Network tab to inspect the response)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I need to apologise. You were right, it does work without the headers part (I will be damned, I spent nights trying to get it to work!!! lol). I had to remove the headers part from the ajax post too. It was causing an error. However the issue still remains that it won't work when logged in. Pretty sure it has to do with the 2 tokens in the serialised string. Interested to know how this could happen. Would it be from another **@Html.AntiForgeryToken()** floating about in the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - It shows:  _The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the <machineKey> configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster._

Comment: That probably explains it - are you running in a Web Farm? Suggest also you google _mvc The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted_ for possible solutions

Comment: If you mean multiple servers clustered, no. I am currently just running on visual studio on my pc and will deploy to a single stand alone server in my garage once done. I hope I understood your question.

Comment: I'm guessing that you might have 2 tokens. You ajax has `$('#config-form').html(result);` but the form you have shown does not have `id="config-form"` so I assume you must have 2 forms. Suggest you start by adding an `id` attribute to the form you have shown and then use `data: $('#yourID').serialize(),` to ensure your only serializing the appropriate form.

Comment: You guessed right. It seems I have multiple tokens being generated. I removed them all but one and it works now but I get **"The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."** when I try and log out. I think I will call this issue resolved and must thank you so much for your help. I will need to muck around with placing the token in the right spot to give the whole site access to it. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Not sure how to give you a tick or a couple of rep points but I would like to as a way to say thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I had multiple @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in my site. I was using partial views and it was being declared in the _LoginPartial view as well as the form I was using posting.

This caused multiple tokens in my form post and it failed validation.